# google glass control camera, callback function is not called

Tags: android, callback, android-camera, google-glass

I write a program, trying to control camera directly. It works well on my phone, but not on the Google Classes and I found out the callback in `camera.takePictures` not called.

The errors look like this:

1.`__PROXY_SetConfig()`

2.`ERROR: failed check:(eError == OMX_ErrorNone) || (eError == OMX_ErrorNoMore)` - returning error Error returned from OMX API in ducati

3.`setCapturingFlag` - Error setting capturing flag!